# How to import custom module in Sonarqube? No name XXX in module YYY

Tags: python, sonarqube, pylint

In my build pipeline I add the sources like this:

```
sonar.sources=moduleA/moduleA
```

However, moduleA at some point imports something from moduleB.

`from moduleB import foo`

Which results in Sonarqube complaining **No name 'foo' in module 'moduleB'**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your project root directory contains sonar-project.properties  and 2 folders(modules) moduleA and moduleB

```
sonar.modules=moduleA,moduleB
```

All sonar.xxx. properties will be inherited by modules unless overridden by module.

```
moduleA.sonar.projectName=Module A is the best
moduleA.sonar.sources=moduleA/moduleA, ../moduleB/moduleB
```

ModuleA has moduleA and B as sources or potentially include moduleB as its own module, or both, do feel free to play around with it.

```
moduleB.sonar.projectName=Module B is the bestest
moduleB.sonar.sources=moduleB/moduleB
```